# OWA 2013 open url with To and Subject fields filled

Tags: outlook-web-access

I've been using OWA 2010 for several years, a I had a way to prefill `To` and `subject` fields with this kind of link:

```
https://{server_name}/owa/?ae=Item&a=New&t=IPM.Note&to={to_address}&subject={custom_subject}
```

Recently my company updated OWA to OWA 2013, and this solution stopped working.

I've found a way to open `compose mail` screen with a link:

```
https://{server_name}/owa/#viewmodel=IMailComposeViewModelFactory
```

But I can't figure out how to fill `To` and `subject` fields.

Are there url parameters for filling `To` and `subject` in OWA 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the path instead of viewmodal. There was a [post on webapps.stackechange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/96126) that seemed to work for me. If this syntax works for you, then be sure to replace spaces with `%20`

The syntax I used:

```
https://{server_name}/owa/&path=/mail/action/compose&to=test@123.com&subject=Subject%20Here
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me - url redirected me to `https://{server_name}/owa/auth/errorFE.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/owa/&path=/mail/action/compose&to=test@123.com&subject=TestSubject` with _something went wrong_ message.

Comment: There must be some other syntax then. I will keep searching and let you know if anything else works for me